# Show listbox in datagridview

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, listbox, show

I am trying to show listbox in but it didnt works, this code in datagridview_mouseClick event:
With debugger it passes all lines below, but show nothing

```
ListBox lb = new ListBox();
 lb.Size = new Size(200, 300);
 lb.Location = new Point(500, 500);
 lb.Items.Add("a");
 lb.Items.Add("b");
 lb.BringToFront();
 listBox1.Show();
```

Any idea where is the problem?
EDIT: My datagridview is in tableLayout and docked - could it be problem?
I am using winforms and c#

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The ListBox has to be contained in something (like your form):

```
this.Controls.Add(lb);
```

The appropriate place to add it depends on where and how you want it to appear.

Comment: yeah great, I forgot about it, when you are doing it in designer, it adds automatically :) thanks